32 MHz xtal on ST MB1874_HP reference schematic questions
I'm designing a PCB heavily based on ST's STDES-WL5U2IHH reference design with the MB1874_HP schematic (extract below). It utilizes a type of crystal I've never used before (NX2016SA 32 MHz EXS00A-CS06465), and the provided schematic has left me somewhat confused.

In the attached picture, you'll notice the use of two 0 ohm resistors, one of which is connected to GND.
The three left-most components have 'NM' written beneath them. I'm unfamiliar with this notation.
In the bottom left corner, there are two sentences:
TCXO: L9/C37/C36/R100/SB13
XTAL: SB13/SB15/C36 = R100 = 0
Are these two sentences referring to distinct use cases?


Image source: ST MB1874_HP schematic

It's a layout that can accept both a crystal or an oscillator for X2. Oscillators are higher performance, but more expensive, so sometimes you want to use them. 
The note is telling you what needs to be done to use each type. TCXO, for the oscillator, place, L9, C37, C36 R100 and SB13. If using a crystal oscillator, place SB13, SB15, and place 0 Ohm resistors in place of C36 and R100. You'd also need to place values for C26 and C31 suitable to load the oscillator. 
NM in this case denotes "Not Mounted" for a component that is not placed. It's a new one for me, and joins a long list of acronyms that all mean the same thing. DNE, DNP, NE, NP, NM.

The 0Ω resistors you reference are shown as capacitors. In the TCXO configuration capacitors are placed, in the crystal configuration they are jumpered with 0Ω resistors.
NM stands for Not Mounted, there are pads for a component but it is not placed during manufacture.
The notes explains changes in the circuit of an TCXO module or a crystal. either can be used with the noted changes to the other components.

The 0R for a capacitor is obviously for the case when you use an XTAL and want to ground the metal lid and in the other case of using a TCXO it must be a bypass cap for supply voltage.

@Justme thanks, I wrote that before getting to the note part of the question.


Ok. In the scenario that is wanted the components are 0 ohm resistors. In another case they aren't.

Likely just means "Not Mounted" literally or something else that equals it.

Yes two use cases, XTAL and TCXO, it reads in the schematics. They require different components and connections so that's why some are not present or some capacitor drawn needs to be a 0 ohm jumper resitor.


So, one set of certain components are used to connect a regular crystal directly to the MCU oscillator pins. Another set of certain components are used to use a TCXO instead, coupling the oscillator output to MCU clock input and to provide the TCXO with power. While also being able to sense which type of oscillator is used in order to configure the MCU crystal pins as oscillator amplifier pins or simply as clock input.
